# Fetching a picture from Gallery

Tags: android

When I am fetching an image from gallery,I get an error on SELECT_PICTURE.
Anybody help me.The code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: Please post error log

Comment: what is the error ? SELECT_PICTURE is a request code, did you give any value to it ? What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

On Button click event, Call this function

```
    private void showImageChooser(){
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Image");
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 500);
    }
```

In OnActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 500 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        imageFile = data.getData();
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageFile).into(profilePic);
    }
}
```

Please use your ImageView in place of profilePic.